# unable to use ruby version 2.4.2p198 using rbenv

Tags: ruby, path, rbenv

I'm trying to use ruby version 2.4.2p198 using rbenv. When running the command `rbenv install --list` the version `2.4.2` is shown but not `2.4.2p198`. I install version `2.4.2` running

`rbenv install 2.4.2p198`

When I run the command `rbenv versions` I see `2.4.2`

When I run my rails server I get the following error message:
[image]

running `$ rbenv global 2.4.2p198` gives me the error 
`` rbenv: version `2.4.2p198' not installed ``

What can I do to install ruby version 2.4.2p198 using rbenv

Comment: `rbenv install 2.4.2-p198`

Comment: @Anthony not found

Comment: if a ruby is absent it may be because your rbenv is old.

Comment: Such Ruby version does not exist: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/

Answer (score 0):

`rbenv rehash` Fixed this issue. `ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]`